# How do I read the value of a custom field of the page?

Tags: custom-field, customization, page-template

When creating custom page templates, how do I get the value of a custom field of the displayed page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [get_post_meta](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta) function.

Answer (score 7):

### WordPress Custom Fields

WordPress custom fields contain a key and a value.  To get both `<?php the_meta(); ?>` will return

```
<ul class='post-meta'>
<li><span class='post-meta-key'>your_key:</span> your_value</li>
</ul>
```

**To return a value stored for a specific key use:**

`<?php get_post_custom_values('my_key', $post_id); ?>`**

**If a post contained more than 1 value for the same key you can use a foreach loop to output all of them i an array:**

```
<?php    
  $mykey_values = get_post_custom_values('my_key');
  foreach ( $mykey_values as $key => $value ) {
    echo "$key  => $value <br />"; 
  }  
?>
```

**This will return:**

```
0 => First value 
1 => Second value
2 => Third value
```

**To return an array of keys within all custom fields use:**

```
<?php get_post_custom_keys($post_id); ?>
```

**Adding custom fields to a post:**

[image]